# How to disable SmartLock Hints?

Tags: smart-lock

[The docs](https://developers.google.com/identity/smartlock-passwords/android/retrieve-hints) explain that an app can ask the API to ask the user to choose an email address to use:

[image: smartlock example hint]

I am always thrown off by that thing popping up after I started typing my email address (in some apps) and in others I still prefer typing it manually to choosing in that huge list (because google adds every address without asking once it is set up in gmail).

How can I make my device act as if I pressed "None of the above" whenever that dialog would pop up?

I am running LineageOS 17 (Android 10), rooted with Magisk.